# Possible to have emuns that can both return string values and know their enum order?

Tags: typescript

I have the following string enum:

```
enum QuotationProgress {
    Designing = 'designing',
    QuoteSent = 'quoteSent',
    QuoteAccepted = 'quoteAccepted',
    Installed = 'installed',
    Done = 'done',
}
```

It describes a process, so `Designing` is before `QuoteSent`, and so on. I would like to do something like:

```
function(currentState, someState) {
    if (someState < currentState) {
        return 'some state is in the past'
    }
}
```

What is a good way to add this order information to the enum?

Comment: TS enums are preserved at run-time through objects making it possible to iterate them in the order of when properties were defined.

Comment: which TS version are you using?
TS 3.4 was recently announced and, perhaps, [const assertions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-4/#const-assertions) is what you're looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enums in TypeScript are not really extensible.  I'd suggest that you keep any extra information in a data structure alongside the enum.

Here's how you could add the ordering as a separate data structure:

```
const quotationProgressOrder: Record<QuotationProgress, number> = {
  [QuotationProgress.Designing]: 0,
  [QuotationProgress.QuoteSent]: 1,
  [QuotationProgress.QuoteAccepted]: 2,
  [QuotationProgress.Installed]: 3,
  [QuotationProgress.Done]: 4,
}  

function f(currentState: QuotationProgress, someState: QuotationProgress) {
  if (quotationProgressOrder[someState] < quotationProgressOrder[currentState]) {
    return 'some state is in the past'
  }
}
```

Depending on your use case, that might be sufficient.  Or, you might find you want to build up your own single enum-like object that holds all the information, and forget about using an `enum` entirely.

Hope that helps.  Good luck!